# Ruby: Multidimensional array to multidimensional hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array:

```
a = [[1,[2,3]], [2,[3,4]], [3,[4,5]]]
```

I want to convert it to:

```
h = {1 => {2 => 3}, 2 => {3 => 4}, 3 => {4 => 5}}
```

I m new to Ruby, can anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: You should check the syntax of your array, the expression `[2,][3,4]` evaluates to `nil`, therefore the array is actually equivalent to: `[[[1, [2, 3]], nil], [3, [4, 5]]]`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Do you control where this array comes from? Could you change the code to output in the required format?

Comment: I edited the question to fix what I believe is a typo. I believe the author intends to use a = [[1,[2,3]], [2,[3,4]], [3,[4,5]]]

Comment: The logic is not clear. If the outermost array consists of pairs, each expressed as an array (like `[1, [2, 3]]`), then how is `[2, 3]` mapped to an inner array? Where are the pairs? If it were `[[2, 3]]`, then I can understand.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean:

```
a = [[1,[2,3]], [2,[3,4]], [3,[4,5]]]
```

---

```
Hash[a.map { |k0, (k, v)| [k0, {k => v}] }]
# => {1=>{2=>3}, 2=>{3=>4}, 3=>{4=>5}}

a.map { |k0, (k, v)| [k0, {k => v}] }.to_h   # Ruby 2.1+
# => {1=>{2=>3}, 2=>{3=>4}, 3=>{4=>5}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
a = [[1, [2, 3]], [2, [3, 4]], [3,[4, 5]]]

a.each_with_object({}) { |(i, (k, v)), h| h[i] = { k => v } }
#=> {1=>{2=>3}, 2=>{3=>4}, 3=>{4=>5}}
```

The nested values are extracted using Ruby's array decomposition:

```
[1, [2, 3]]
(i, (k, v))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented nicely as a map/reduce:

```
a = [[1, [2, 3]], [2, [3, 4]], [3,[4, 5]]]

a.map{|k,v| {k=>v}}.reduce(:merge) 
# => {1=>{2=>3}, 2=>{3=>4}, 3=>{4=>5}}
```

The map turns each sub-array into a tiny hash, and the reduce iteratively applies Hash#merge to combine them into one big hash.

This is more concise than other implementations I've seen, and also more readable/idiomatic (at least to my eye).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, which I'm suggesting because a) the standard approaches have already been mentioned in answers posted earlier; and b) you might find it instructive, if not a bit bizarre.

What we will do is create an empty hash `h` and then execute:

```
a.each { |k| h[k] }
```

and presto!

```
h => {1=>{2=>3}, 2=>{3=>4}, 3=>{4=>5}}
```

"How can that possibly be?", you probably are thinking. The trick is the way we define the hash `h`; namely, we use the form of the class method [Hash::new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,(x,(y,z))| h[x] = { y=>z } }
```

It's normally used like this:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = ... } }
```

This says that when `h` is passed a key `k` that is not already in the hash, the block is to be executed to compute the value associated with the new key.  We do not, however, need to use `k` as the key. Here I am passing an element of `a`, which I have written in its decomposed (or "disambiguted") form, `(x,(y,z))`, and then adding the key-value pair `x => { y=>z }` to the hash.

This could instead be written:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k.first] = { k.last.first=>k.last.last } }
```

but I hope you will agree that the decomposed form is a lot easier to read.

Rather than:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,(x,(y,z))| h[x] = { y=>z } }
a.each { |k| h[k] }
h
```

the more Ruby-like way is:

```
a.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,(x,(y,z))| h[x] = { y=>z } }) { |k,h| h[k] }
```